# SQL get ALL rows which share foreign keys

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

I wish to find ALL rows which have at least one sibling with some(not specific) foreign key.

```
mytable
id |fk_id    
---|--------
1  |100 
2  |200
3  |200
4  |300 
5  |300
6  |300
```

My query should return rows 2 to 6, but not row 1 since it is alone.

I came up with a working solution which uses 2 subqueries which seems too much. (Running a few seconds on 20k+ rows, which implies at least O(n^2)

```
SELECT * from mytable 
WHERE fk_id IN 
  (SELECT fk_id FROM
    (SELECT fk_id, SUM(fk_id) as mycnt from mytable GROUP BY fk_id)
  WHERE mycnt >= 2)
```

What would be a faster solution?

Regular programming Non SQL solution would be to just sort by fk_id and then get rid of singles which would be O(nlogn) for generic sorting plus O(n) just to iterate over once, so O(nlogn)

Using SQLite, but other SQL dialects are fine too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With EXISTS:

```
SELECT m.* FROM mytable m
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM mytable
  WHERE id <> m.id AND fk_id = m.fk_id
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2stqyTFLLcc9YWQXhR1XL8/0).
Or with COUNT() window function:

```
SELECT m.id, m.fk_id 
FROM (
  SELECT *, COUNT(id) OVER (PARTITION BY fk_id) counter  
  FROM mytable
) m
WHERE m.counter > 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2stqyTFLLcc9YWQXhR1XL8/2).
Results:

```
| id  | fk_id |
| --- | ----- |
| 2   | 200   |
| 3   | 200   |
| 4   | 300   |
| 5   | 300   |
| 6   | 300   |
```

Comment: Thank You!  Nice to know about different options :)

Comment: I am actually surprised on how quick EXISTS version works, maybe because I added indexing to foreign key.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
select * 
from mytable
where fk_id in (
  select fk_id
  from mytable
  group by fk_id
  having count(*) > 1
)
```

Another alternative using `inner join`:

```
select * 
from mytable m
inner join
(
  select fk_id
  from mytable
  group by fk_id
  having count(*) > 1
) fks on fks.fk_id = m.fk_id
```

Comment: Thank You! That is indeed faster :)

Comment: @Sint *That is indeed faster* Only if source table is compact enough, else WHERE EXISTS may be more fast.